# Resource not found when encoded url is passed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

When I call following url from my ionic app, I get error:

```
http://localhost:56776/api/Account/%2B17276669901/RequestResetCode?language=en-US&countryId=9305  404 (Not Found)
```

This is what my typrscript file has:

```
  var url=  AppSettings.API_URL + 'api/Account/' + encodeURIComponent(phone) + '/RequestResetCode' + lang + '&countryId=' + AppSettings.PREFERRED_COUNTRY;
    return this.http.post(url,'');
```

Looks like encodeURIComponent is unable to handle '+' when it passed along with phone number.This works when I pass the phone number without '+' symbol.Thanks for looking into this. Just FYI I have asp.net web api to cater this request.Is there something that I need to configure on my api in stead?

Backend:

On Controller level:  `[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [HttpOptions]       
        [Route("{UserLoginName}/RequestResetCode")]
        public IHttpActionResult RequestResetCode([FromUri]string userLoginName, [FromUri]string language = null)
        {
            new Application.Service.RequestResetCode(userLoginName, language);
            return Ok();
        }

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Why are you encoding the Phone Number? +'s don't break URLs

Comment: because same method is called for email as well.I mean  one can pass email as well instead of phone number.

Comment: so, `phone` can be both, a phone number, and an email address?

Comment: yes it can be any of them.

Comment: Now, can you share the code from your backend? 404  really doesn't make much sense :)

Comment: Added in question details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170104/discussion-between-kumar-and-luca).